# Using custom cname for uploads with aws ios sdk

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

We're using the aws ios sdk to upload media to s3 but would like to use a different hostname (eg I'd like to cname up.ourdomain.com -> s3.amazonaws.com). Does anyone know if thats possible without too much hacking? I don't want it to be impossible to upgrade the sdk in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I help maintain the AWS SDK for iOS.  While I can't recommend that you proceed with this plan, you can set the endpoint on the service client like so:

```
 s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
 s3.endpoint = @"up.ourdomain.com";
```

While this should work with global operations (listing buckets for instance), the SDK will expect that `BUCKETNAME.up.ourdomain.com` exists for any bucket you try to create or access directly.  If you can guarantee that this will be the case then you may not run into any additional problems.

Can I ask why you feel the need to add an additional layer of indirection?

Comment: +1. Unless you really need to get clever with the hostname, you shouldn't risk breakage.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful. I'm not convinced I need to change it yet but was weighing the option. If we use a cname, we could (in theory) move existing clients to a new backend transparently if we really needed to.

Comment: @ColinKroll Will your customers ever access the up.ourdomain.com domain directly other than through your application?  If not, I don't think will you save yourself (or your users) anything should you choose to move away from S3 in the future as you will still have to replace any code that is uploading the files to the backend.

Comment: @ColinKroll What you may want to consider is if you are using a single bucket (or a manageable set of buckets), you could alias each of their DNS names in your subdomain (BUCKET1.ourdomain.com -> BUCKET1.s3.amazonaws.com) but still use the standard s3 endpoints for uploads.  This is a very common setup I myself have used in other projects.